# DDD Abordagem tática - Agregados e Repositórios

Tags: php, ddd, repository

Estou estudando sobre DDD e tentando aplicar seus conceitos. Estou com dúvidas sobre alguns conceitos no que diz respeito a parte tática do DDD.

### Problemática

Vamos lá! Supondo que eu tenha um agregado **Client** e este possui uma lista de desejos. Cada item da lista corresponde a um **Product**.

Dito isso, se eu precisar remover um item da lista, recorro a entidade **Client**. Algo como:

```
$client->removeFromWishList(Product $product))
```

O método **removeFromWishList(...)** contém algumas regras que precisam estar em conformidade para remoção. Se tudo estiver ok, o produto será removido da lista de desejos contida no objeto **Client**.

Porém essa remoção é só em memória. Então utilizo uma **Application Service**, que tem acesso ao repositório que irá tratar da remoção. A pergunta é: O que o repositório que contém o método de remoção deverá receber como argumento?

---

### Abordagem

1. Caso receba como argumento o objeto **Client**:
   Como saberei qual produto terei de remover uma vez que tal produto não está mais na lista de desejos?
   Ex.:

   ```
   $clientRepository->removeFromWishList(Client $client)
   ```
2. Caso receba como argumento o objeto **Product** ou o **id do produto** que será removido:
   Dessa forma, eu entendo que estaria removendo qualquer produto sem passar pelo método **removeFromWishList(...)** ignorando as regras que garantem a remoção citada anteriormente.

   Ex.:

   ```
   $clientRepository->removeFromWishList(Product $product)
   ```

   Ou:

   ```
   $clientRepository->removeFromWishList($productId)
   ```

Não ficou claro para mim qual das abordagens citadas (ou nenhuma delas...) seria a ideal.

Da mesma forma não entendo se terei de carregar todos os produtos da lista de desejos para o objeto **Client** sempre que eu quiser remover um produto da lista (passando pelas regras que garantem a remoção).

Desde já agradeço pela atenção.

Answer (score 1):

O que o repositório que contém o método de remoção deverá receber como argumento? Basicamente o id do produto a ser removido, o id da sessão/cache do usuário para confirmar que ele está removendo do próprio "carrinho".

Comment: Primeiramente obrigado pela atenção. Entendi sua colocação, porém, nesse caso eu poderia estar removendo um item do carrinho sem passar pelas regras de remoção, certo?

Mesmo que antes de chamar o método do repositório eu realizar a remoção "em memória, isto é, passando pelo método que garante a remoção segura",  teria de passar o ids de forma manual e sem qualquer garantia de validação. (Não sei se fui claro.... rs). Nesse ponto, qualquer programador poderia remover um item de uma lista e esquecer que antes deveria ter removido tal item passando pelo método de remoção do domínio.

Comment: Não teria como remover manualmente, essa lista é apenas o armazenamento do que PRETENDO remover, a remoção mesmo só é efetivada pelo seu método "removeWish..." com suas regras. Mesmo que ele altere manualmente os valores, eles serão forçados a passar pelas suas regras, como você mostrou "$client->removeFromWishList(Product $product))", aqui você está obrigando os itens (dentro de $product) a passar pela "removeWish...", o processamento das regras é no servidor, não no cliente.

Comment: Eu havia postado essa mesma questão, porém, de maneira mais detalhada em https://github.com/laravelbrasil/forum/issues/206